# Polynomial Interpolation And polynomial Roots

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials, interpolation, lagrange-interpolation

Given $\{(x_1,y_1),...,(x_n,y_n)\}$, we can interpolate a polynomial $P$. Assume polynomial $P$ has some roots including an specific root $\beta$.

Consider we change one of $y_i$ to $y'_i$. Given $\{(x_1,y_1),...,(x_i,y'_i),..,(x_n,y_n)\}$ we interpolate a polynomial $P'$.

**Question 1**: Would it be possible that $P'$ has the root $\beta$, too?

**Question 2**: Would it be possible that $P'$ has the same degree as $P$ and $P'$ has the root $\beta$, too?

Notation: $y_i$ is defined as $P(x_i)=y_i$

Edit:  $x_i \neq0$ , $x_i\neq x_j$, the polynomials, $x_i$'s and $y_i$'s are defined over finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$ for a large prime $p$.

Comment: It's certainly possible that $P$ and $P'$ share a root, with the trivial case being where one of the points that is unchanged, say $(x_1,y_1)$, has $y$-coordinate $0$.

Comment: I don't really see why you want to specify $x_i\neq 0$. Up to a translation you can always assume one of your $x_i$ is zero, and this won't change anything to the answers to both your questions.

Comment: @Arnaud Ok, in my protocol, that condition was required I wanted to mention.

Comment: the crucial question is, which degree shall $P$ and $P'$ have at most?

Comment: @user251257 Their degree shall not be higher than $n-1$.

Comment: Then, @Arnaud's answer is correct. The interpolating polynomial is unique. cf. for example [Newton polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polynomial).

Comment: @user251257 His answer is correct, but why it is correct? Why cannot I change one (or many) of $y_i$'s but still interpolate a polynomial $P'$ with the same degree as $P$? I need some theorem that I can use. It might be trivial for you mathematicians, but I need a proof, to prove it in my protocol.

Comment: As @Arnaud already has explained: If $\beta$ was a root of $P$ and $P'$, then both are of degree $\le n-1$ and interpolate $(x_1,y_1), \dotsc, (x_{i-1},y_{i-1})$, $(x_{i+1},y_{i+1}), \dotsc, (x_{n},y_{n})$, $(\beta, 0)$. Thus, by uniqueness $P=P'$ and $y_i = P(x_i) = P'(x_i) = y_i'$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: @user251257 How can we argue when more that one $y_i$ is changed?

Comment: @user13676 if you allow 2 values to be changed, than $\beta$ can be the root of $P$ and $P'$.

Comment: @user251257 Why can $\beta$ be the root of $P$ and $P'$ in that case?

Comment: @user13676 because $P$ and $P'$ intersect at  $n-1$ points only.

Comment: @user251257 Can I chat with you for 10 minutes, if yes please invite me to the chatroom.

Comment: @user13676 I am on mobile. can't chat. sorry :/

Comment: @user251257 You're saying, in that case, $P'$ can be a polynomial of degree at most $n-1$ and have root $\beta$. If yes, what is probability that $P'$ has $\beta$ if we pick $\beta$ uniformly random from the field.

Comment: @user13676 you should ask that as a new question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually if $\beta$ is not one of your $x_j$'s then it's impossible. Indeed, the two polynomials $P$ and $P'$ have degree $n-1$ (at most) and take the same value on all $x_j$ for $j\neq i$ (namely, $y_j$), so if they both vanished at $\beta$ they would have the same value at $n$ points, and thus they would be equal, which is not the case since they have different values at $x_i$.

Of course, as pointed out in the comments, if $\beta=x_j\neq x_i$ then $P$ and $P'$ trivially a common root.

Comment: @Arnnaud  Many thanks for the answer. Since my background is mainly computer science not math, I may ask some questions that look trivial to you mathematicians. First, I need to know why "it is impossible... if $x_i\neq\beta$ ". It would be great if you refer me to a theorem or a proof. Second, what if more than one values of $y_i$ can be changed. What would be an answer to questions 1 and 2, in this case? Thank you.

Comment: Can I have your answer for this question please: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1405820/polynomial-interpolation-and-security