# Polynomial Interpolation and Security

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, abstract-algebra, polynomials, interpolation

Let polynomial $P$ be $P(x)=g(x).(x−β)$, where $g$ is a polynomial and $\beta \leftarrow \mathbb{F}_p$. We evaluate $P$ at some $\textbf{x}=(x_1,..,x_n)$. This gives us $\textbf{y}=(y_1,..,y_n)$. Assume some of $y_i$'s are accidentally changed to some random values $y′_i$'s. Now we interpolate $(x_1,y_1),...,(x_i,y′_i),..(x_j,y′_j),...(x_n,y_n)$, to get a polynomial $P′$.

**My question**: What is the probability that $P′$ has the root β?

*Definitions*: $y_i$ is defined as $P(x_i)=y_i$, $x_i \neq0$ , $x_i\neq x_j$, the polynomials, $x_i$'s and $y_i$'s are defined over finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$ for a large prime $p$.

Comment: $P'$ is the polynomial interpolating the $n$ points in $S$, so it certainly has degree $n-1$ at most. But I don't understand how you choose $\beta$. If it's picked randomly among the elements in your field $\mathbb{F}_p$ there is no reason that it should be a root of $P$...

Comment: @Arnaud We first define $P$ where $P=g.(x-\beta)$, where $g$ is a polynomial. Then evaluate $P$ at some $\textbf{x}=(x_1,..,x_n)$. This gives us $\textbf{y}=(y_1,..,y_n)$. Assume  some of $y_i$'s are accidentally changed to some random values $y'_i$'s. Now we interpolate  $(x_1,y_1),...,(x_i,y'_i),..(x_j,y'_j),...(x_n,y_n)$, to get a polynomial $P'$. My question is what is the probability that $P'$ has the root $\beta$.

Comment: I'm editing the question.

Comment: Ah I understand better now. Can we assume that we know exactly how many $y_i$'s are changed? Or do we only know that there has been some change, but without any detail?

Comment: @Arnaud In fact I want it for data integrity check, so we do not know anything about the changes. That is why we insert $\beta$ to let us detect such a change, so we know $\beta$. But I need to know how sure I can be with this check.

Comment: @Arnaud Here is my answer When $\textbf{all}$ $y_i$'s are changed: Assume given $(x_1,y'_1),...(x_n,y'_n)$, we could interpolate polynomial $P'$ whose degree is at most $n-1$. Then $P'$ has at most $n-1$ roots, thus the probability that one of them is $\beta$ equals $\frac{n-1}{p}$ that is negligible. But I do not know how to argue when small number of $y_i$'s are changed.

Comment: But that can't be right : if $n>p+1$ this would give you a probability $>1$...

Comment: @user13676 Presumably $P'$ has degree $\le n-1$ so that it's uniquely defined.  What can you tell us about the degree of $P$ itself?  Is it exactly equal to $n-1$ or is the number of sample points substantially larger (or smaller) than the degree of $P$?

Comment: @Arnaud You can't sample $> p+1$ points in $\mathbb F_p$.

Comment: @Arnaud that is Ok, because $n$ is at most 100 or 10000000 but $P$ that is one of the protocol's security parameter that is sufficiently large e.g. 256-bit

Comment: @ Erick Wong of course, that was dumb of me. Didn't really think much before writing that, sorry.

Comment: @ErickWong Your question is not very clear to me. Let assume that the degree of polynomial $P$ is at most $n-1$. We do not know degree of $P'$, and we do not know if we can interpolate $P'$ whose degree is at most $n-1$.

Comment: @Arnaud Thank you for the answer. What is not clear to me is the case where two or more $y_i$'s are changed. Could you give some hints about that please.

Comment: @user13676 Given $n$ distinct points, you can always interpolate them to a unique polynomial of degree at most $n-1$.  If you're really saying that $P'$ could have larger degree than that, then you need to give more detail about what "Now we interpolate" means, because otherwise your  $P'$ is not well-defined and your question is unanswerable.  But my question was about the degree of $P$, not $P'$.

Comment: @ErickWong Yes you are right.  In the comment I mentioned the application. In fact what I want is the probability that given the modified $y_i$'s we can interpolate polynomial $P'$ that has the specific root $\beta$. Now my concern is whether the number of unchanged $y_i$'s can increase the chance that $\beta$ appear among $P'$'s roots.

Comment: @user13676 To put it simply, given the starting polynomial $P$, how do you decide how large $n$ is?  Is $n$ chosen to exactly match $1+\deg P$?  Or is $n$ chosen to be deliberately larger (for redundancy which is a desirable trait of data integrity schemes)?  Or is $n$ chosen to be deliberately smaller (because compactness is also a desirable trait)?  I think this might have a significant impact on the probability, but your question doesn't describe the degree of $P$ at all (except that it's at least $1$ since it contains a linear factor)

Comment: @ErickWong $n$ is fixed and should be large; however, we set polynomial $P$ in a way that it has $n-1$ degree. One way to do is that we insert some dummy values as the roots. By large I mean $n=10^6$ but not larger than that. But $p$, prime value is at least 256-bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability is $\frac{1}{p}$.

One way to see this is to imagine that instead of $(x_n,y_n')$ you take $(\beta,0)$ as an interpolation point. Then you get a unique polynomial $\tilde{P}$ of degree at most $n-1$ satisfying $\tilde{P}(x_i)=y_i'$ for $i<n$ and $\tilde{P}(\beta)=0$. Let $\tilde{y_n}=\tilde{P}(x_n)$. You know that $P'$ has degree at most $n-1$ and satisfies $P'(x_i)=y_i'$ for all $i$, thus in particular for $i<n$. It follows from the uniqueness of interpolation polynomials that $P'(\beta)=0$ iff $P'=\tilde{P}$ iff $\tilde{y}_n=\tilde{P}(x_n)=y_n'$, and since $y_n'$ is taken uniformly randomly in $\mathbb{F}_p$, the probability that $y_n'=\tilde{y}_n$ is $\frac{1}{p}$.

Note : I treated the problem like all $y_i$ had been changed to values $y_i'$, which are possibly equal to $y_i$.

Comment: What if some of $y_i$'s are changed (e.g. two or three of them)? Am I right that the other unchanged $y_i$'s may increase the chance that $\beta$ appear in the interpolating polynomial's root?

Comment: Actually the number of values changed doesn't influence the result in my answer.

Comment: @Arnaud Before the clarification that $\deg P = n-1$, it wasn't necessarily true that $\tilde{P}(\beta) = 0$ (for instance, if $\deg P > n$, then just knowing that $P(\beta)=0$ does not imply much about $\tilde{P}(\beta)$ :).

Comment: What do you mean? $\tilde{P}(\beta)=0$ by definition of $\tilde{P}$

Comment: @Arnaud I think in "satisfies $P(x_i)=y′_i $",  $P$ should be $P'$

Comment: @Arnaud So when a subset of $y_i$'s (but not all) are changed we say; given $(x_1,y_1),...(x_i,y'_i),...,(x_j,y'_j),...,(x_n,y'_n)$ we  interpolate polynomial $P'$ of degree at most $n-1$. Now we replace $(x_n,y'_n)$ with $(\beta,0)$ then we interpolate polynomial $\hat{P}$. And the rest is exactly according to your answer. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. (Also I corrected the typo you mentioned. I hope there is no other one.)

Comment: @Arnaud Thank you for the answers.

Comment: @Arnaud Have a look at this question if you are interested please:    http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1406962/polynomial-interpolation-and-polynomial-multiplication

Comment: @MorganRodgers Can we say anything if $y'_i$ values are NOT uniformly random values, instead they are arbitrary values?

Comment: @ArnaudD. Can we say anything if $y'_i$ values are NOT uniformly random values, instead they are arbitrary values?

Comment: @user13676 What do you mean by arbitrary values? As I have explained, it depends on the values $y_i$.

Comment: @ArnaudD. I do know that your above answer is based on the fact that the modified values are uniformly random. I need to know (and it's very important to me to know ) whether we determine the probability that $P'(\beta)=0$ when the modified values are not uniformly random. I do appreciate for your help.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Here is one example: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/216057/interpolating-product-of-two-polynomials

Comment: @MorganRodgers Thank you for the answer. If you had a chance could you please look at this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1414892/polynomial-interpolation-when-part-of-y-is-are-shuffled

Comment: @ArnaudD. Consider the case where the $y_i'$ distributions are not completely uniformly random, instead they are close to uni.random; for instance a distribution of $y'_i$ is in $[\frac{1}{p-1}+\frac{1}{(p-1)^2},\frac{1}{p-1}-\frac{1}{(p-1)^2}]$. Is it correct that your answer would be changed to  $\frac{1}{p-1}-\frac{1}{(p-1)^2}$.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Is the above question corollary or lemma?