# Polynomial Interpolation When part of $y_i$'s are Shuffled

Tags: probability, polynomials, probability-distributions, permutations, interpolation

Hypothesis: Let $\vec{x}=[x_1,...,x_n]$ be elements of field $\mathbb{Z}_p$, where $p$ is a large prime. $x_i \neq x_j$, $x_i \in \mathbb{Z}_p$. Note $x_i$ values are **NOT** picked uniformly random and they are fixed values. Let $\beta$ be a field element picked uniformly random. Assume we have $\vec{r}=[r_1,..r_n]$, where $r_i\neq0, r_i \in \mathbb{Z}_p$. A subset (but not all) of $r_i$ can be 1. For those $r_i$ that are not 1 we have $r_i\neq r_j$. The $r_i$ values are **NOT** picked uniformly at random.

---

We define $T(x)=(x-\beta)\cdot g(x)$. So $T(x)$ is product of two polynomials $x-\beta$ and $g(x)$. Degree of $T(x)$ is fixed $n-1$, and the polynomials are defined over the field. We evaluate $T(x)$ at the elements of $\vec{x}$. This yields vector $\vec{y}=[y_1,...,y_n]$ where $T(x_i)=y_i$

Given $(x_1,y_1\cdot r_1),...,(x_n,y_n\cdot r_n)$ we interpolate polynomial $T'$, and we assume $T'$ has root $\beta$.

We shuffle the elements in $\vec{r}$ so an element in $i^{th}$ position is moved to a uniformly random $s^{th}_i$ position: $r_i \rightarrow r_{s_i}$

Given $(x_1,y_1\cdot r_{s_1}),...,(x_n,y_n\cdot r_{s_n})$ we interpolate polynomial $T''$.

---

**Question**: What is the probability that $T''$ has root $\beta$ ?

Comment: Well, I see that you removed $P(x)$, but $g(x)$ is still undefined, as are $x_i, y_i, r_i$.  I get the sense that this is taken out of context, and in context all of those things are defined.  As it stands, though, I can't really make sense out of it.

Comment: @lulu we define polynomial $P(x)$ as a product of two polynomials ,namely, $g(x)$ and $(x-\beta)$. $x_i$'s are elements of the field. So we can pick $n$ values of $x_i$ from the field. Then we evaluate $P$ at these $x_i$'s, so $\forall i, 1 \leq i \leq n, P(x_i)=y_i\cdot r_i$.

Comment: I take it $P(x)$ is still $T(x)$? The $x_i$ are chosen uniformly except that they must all be distinct and they must avoid the roots of $T(x)$?  Any other restrictions?  Why do you write $T(x_i)$ as a product?  On its face it would seem that the answer to your question will depend on how you "factor" the values of $T(x_i)$, no?  I mean, it seems I can take $r_i=1$ for $i>1$ and then take $r_1$ to be pretty much whatever I want.  Surely I will get a different answer each time, no?

Comment: Still not clear. The numbers $y_i$ suddenly appear on the scene out of nowhere. What are they? Some elements chosen in advance? Also, what do we know about $g(x)$? What do we know about $\beta$? Apparently we must have $\beta\neq x_i$ for all $i$, for if $\beta=x_i$, then $r_i\cdot y_i=0$ violating what you state in the end.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen As you may have noticed, we factor $y'_i=P(x_i)$ into two values $y_i$ and $r_i$. so $y'_i=y_i\cdot r_i$

Comment: Could you please rewrite the question in such a way that all the variables and polynomials (together with the constraints they must satisfy) are given BEFORE you use them for the first time.

Comment: But $P(x_i)$ can be factored like that in $p-1$ different ways. If $P(x_i)$ is some non-zero element of $\Bbb{Z}_p$, then we can let $y_i$ be any non-zero element of $\Bbb{Z}_p$, and that will give us a unique $r_i$. What I am saying is that the equation $P(x_i)=y_i\cdot r_i$ can determine either $y_i$ or $r_i$. Not both. Which is it? And how do we know the other?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I've edited (changed) the question. Please let me know if there is any ambiguity.

Comment: Looks better to me now. Assuming that we know nothing about $g(x)$ except that its coefficients are in $\Bbb{Z}_p$ and $\deg g\le n-2$.

Comment: Related, by the same user: [Specific root of interpolating polynomial](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1412856/specific-root-of-interpolating-polynomial) and [Under what condition... can we interpolate polynomial T that has specific random root?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1414684/under-what-condition-given-x-1-y-1-cdot-r-1-x-n-y-n-cdot-r-n-we-can).

Comment: When you say that $r_i$ is sent to a uniformly random position $r_{s_i}$, do you mean that each $s_i$ is uniformly random between $1$ and $n$, with $s_i$ and $s_j$ independant (so they could possibly be equal) ? Or do you mean that the permutation $s:i\to s_i$ is taken uniformly random in the symmetric group $S_n$? I think the second option makes more sense as "shuffling" but I want to be sure I get the question right.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Thank you very much for reading the question. Yes, the second option is correct.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Hi, Do you think we cannot argue about the probability in the above question?